# Wrong Domain Being Picked Up In My Urls

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem where the wrong domain seems to be picked up.

I have something like this

```
<a href="/forgotpassword/">Forgot password?</a>
```

my domain is is localhost:8081

I would expect the link to be `http://localhost:8081/forgotpassword` yet it is  `http://localhost/forgotpassword`

For some reason the port number gets dropped, I am seeing this on all browser(IE 10, FF, Chrome)

Comment: Are you being **redirected** from `http://localhost:8081/forgotpassword` to `http://localhost/forgotpassword`?

Comment: When I look at the link from firebug it looks like "localhost" and when I click on it, it does just go to  http://localhost/forgotpassword

Comment: How is the Url generated? Did you just write `/forgotpassword/` or you're using some helper to generate the Url?

Comment: just how I wrote it in my OP, On another computer the correct domain is shown, it is just my computer that is failing.

Comment: Well, this simply should not be happening, and it would be a pretty major bug across all of these browsers if it was browser-related (not bloody likely). It's something with your machine, and that could really be anything. It's pretty much impossible for anyone to help you without being able to actually be in front of your computer. What kind of security software do you have running? Is this a corporate box or your personal machine? If corporate, what kind of security software does your company employ? Heck it could even be some sort of malware on your machine. There's just no telling.